# what does express-async-handler do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I am trying to comprehend what does express-async-handler do?

It was used in one of the repo I was looking.

From their docs, it says

> Simple middleware for handling exceptions inside of async express
>   routes and passing them to your express error handlers.

Link for the repo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

Can someone please explain this with example?

Comment: Saves you writing your own `try/catch` for `async/await` and passes error on to `next`. When in doubt go look at the source code

Comment: Oh wow, a 4 line package ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The example in the npm page shows this:

```
express.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const bar = await foo.findAll();
    res.send(bar)
}))
```

Without asyncHandler you'd need:

```
express.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
    foo.findAll()
    .then ( bar => {
       res.send(bar)
     } )
    .catch(next); // error passed on to the error handling route
})
```

The first one uses the async / await language elements and is more concise.

Comment: I have a question, there is async await used in the function. But it is necessary to use express async handler package?

Comment: What will happen if I use the first example without wrapping inside `asyncHandler`?

Comment: @MarinosAn you can definitely write without wrapping asyncHandler but then you also need to write try catch block with async await for every function or route, using asyncHandler prevents us from writing repetitive try catch block in every request route function

Answer (score 2):

You have to install npm package --> npm i express-async-handler.

```
//import package
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

//when using async handler
//wrap the async function with asynchandler
//like this asyncHandler(async fn())
const getRequest = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
if(req.body.xxxx)
{
   const response = await db.collection.find();
   res.status(200).send("success");
}
else{
   res.status(400).send("failed");
//we can simply throw error like this
   throw new Error("Something went wrong")
}

})
```

No need to worry about returning try catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have arrow functions methods in your class. A very example below:

```
export class UserController {
  public auth = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    return response.status(200).json({})
  }
}

app.post('/users/auth', new UserController().auth);
```

If you methods fallow other pattern, for a reason can be return error. So only do that.

Done! :)